# Analog Hawking radiation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, black-holes, quantum-gravity, research-level, hawking-radiation

I am confused by most discussions of analog 
Hawking radiation in fluids (see, for example, 
the recent experimental  result of Weinfurtner et 
al. [Phys. Rev. Lett. 106, 021302 (2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.021302), [arXiv:1008.1911](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1911)). The starting 
point of these discussions is the observation that 
the equation of motion for fluctuations around 
stationary solutions of the Euler equation have
the same mathematical structure as the wave 
equation in curved space (there is a fluid metric
$g_{ij}$ determined by the background flow). This 
background metric can have sonic horizons. The 
sonic horizons can be characterized by an associated 
surface gravity $\kappa$, and analog Hawking temperature 
$T_H \sim \kappa\hbar/c_s$.

My main questions is this: Why would $T_H$ be relevant? 
Corrections to the Euler flow are not determined by 
quantizing small oscillations around the classical flow.
Instead, hydrodynamics is an effective theory, and 
corrections arise from higher order terms in the derivative 
expansion (the Navier-Stokes, Burnett, super-Burnett terms), 
and from thermal fluctuations. Thermal fluctuations are 
governed by a linearized hydro theory with Langevin forces, 
but the strength of the noise terms is governed by the 
physical temperature, not by Planck's constant.

A practical question is: In practice $T_H$ is very small
(because it is proportional to $\hbar$). How can you 
claim to measure thermal radiation at a temperature
$T_H << T$?

Comment: Great question!

Comment: @Thomas, I went ahead and merged both accounts, to avoid confusion, hope that is OK with you.

Comment: Just a few remarks. Firstly, GR is also an effective theory, with higher order corrections in the string length expansion. Secondly, I also don't understand how quantum effects can be measured in such a setting. Maybe it's possible for very low temperatures but then we need something like liquid Helium

Comment: FWIF John Baez had a blog post over at Azimuth about this topic: http://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/liquid-light

Comment: @Tim. I don't think John's post on liquid light is related to Unruh's dumb hole.

Comment: John indeed mentions a possible analogue of Hawking radiation in polariton liquid. However in this case it might actually make sense since the polariton liquid is quantum (i.e. the wavelength isn't small w.r.t. the mean free path)

Comment: Indeed, I refer to the Weinfurtner et al paper because I find this particularly puzzling (they have a water tank). But I am confused even in the case of quantum fluids: 1) Ordinary (non superfluid) quantum fluids are described by standard hydro, the only thing that is quantum is the microscopic kinetic description. 2) In superfluids, it is indeed the case that the normal components can be described (in some limit) as a gas of quantized sound waves (phonons). But even in this situation you would think that the main effect is ordinary thermal fluctuations at temperature T.

Comment: @Thomas: I used to be puzzled by this a bit when I was doing stuff on it. I think I eventually convinced myself that it's because the thermal state you get is actually "classical", in that e.g. as a Wigner distribution it's always positive. That turns out to be the weird thing about Unruh/Hawking radiation ---  the form is actually not very quantum at all.

Comment: Maybe, but the temperature is proportional to $\hbar$, so I would call it quantum.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you call it --- it's still perfectly described as classical...

Comment: If you have radiation at a rate proportional to $\hbar$, how can it not be a quantum effect?

Comment: Thomas I think this effect should be noticeable when the external temperature is not very high with respect to the Hawking temperature, that is, the external temperature has to be very low. This is why I don't think it makes sense for water which cannot remain liquid at low temperatures

Comment: The sonic analogue of Unruh effect is fully classical. You can read more about it in G.E. Volovik's book, "The universe in a helium droplet". The $\hbar$ you mention is merely metaphorical.

Comment: @Thomas : [Stefan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) has some $\hbar$ in it, so any ember in your fireplace glows throug a quantum effect, according to your reasoning.

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans: and, of course, blackbody radiation was how quantum mechanics was originally discovered in the first place.

Comment: We are moving away from the initial question ...  Regarding black body radiation Jeremy is of course correct in stating that this is a quantum effect (the classical calculation of the energy density of thermal EM radiation is UV divergent, and this divergence is regularized in QM). There is an interesting question whether there is an analogous divergence in fluid dynamics.  I'm not completely sure, since high momentum sound waves are strongly damped.

Comment: The important point is this: 1) The dominant contribution to the energy are the kinetic and internal energy, as well as gradient corrections (dissipative terms), 2) Fluctuations are a higher order effect, and in general UV (cutoff) sensitive. This is expected for an effective field theory. 3) The UV completion is not a quantum theory of sound waves, but a kinetic theory (classical or quantum, depending on the fluid) of the microscopic degrees of freedom (typically atoms).

Comment: The analogy is almost ridiculous, like comparing the moon to a supernova.  Although it may seem a little too simple, a 2019 alternative to HR is suggested at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10819.pdf .

Answer (score 10):

The conditions for the existence of the Hawking effect are described in classical terms, i.e you need

1) A Lorentz signature metric

2) A horizon (given, for example, by [space flowing into a BH](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060) faster than the speed of light, or fluid flowing downstream faster than the speed of sound)

3) Surface gravity at the horizon

Those conditions are then applied to a quantum field which satisfies a wave equation (e.g. Klein Gordon field on spacetime).  The standard analysis proceeds by treating photon paths as null geodesics (eikonal approximation).  The acoustic analogue of this is that sound waves (the quantum excitations of which are phonons) follow null geodesics in the Lorentzian acoustic metric.  So my guess is that the reason for the presence of Planck's constant in the Hawking temperature expression in the acoustic case is that they're treating Hawking radiation in the phonon (quantum) field.

Indeed, [Visser](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712010) says

> an acoustic event horizon will emit Hawking radiation in the form of a
>   thermal bath of phonons at a temperature

$$kT_H=\frac{\hbar g_H}{2\pi c} $$

Here $g_H$ is the acoustic surface gravity and $c$ is the speed of sound

Comment: Can you please suggest a reference for the three conditions you have stated above? Thank you.

Comment: I realized that you already gave a reference. Sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I remember attending a seminar by Unruh a few months ago and the same question arised. As far as I remember, he enfasized that in these hydrodynamic analogs of black holes, the flow is not quantized, it is a classical fluid, and everything is classical and that the dumb hole behaves like a quantum amplifier emitting quantum noise from the Horizon. Calculations indicate that the spectrum of these outgoing phonons must be "thermal" (like in black hole case) and a small temperature can be associated to it. I would not call this temperature "quantum", even if it is proportional to $\hbar$ since it can be completely determined from classical attributes of the fluid (speed of flow, adiabatic properties of the fluid, etc) which can be measured classically. The appearance of $\hbar$ is supposed to be a consequence of quantum amplification of the "phonon field" near the Horizon.

Looking at the experimental paper I don't see anywhere a direct measurement of temperature. They don't stick a thermometer in the water stream (for obvious reasons). They just verify that the dumb hole seems to have a "thermal character" while acting on surface waves. They just measure the amplitude of ingoing and outgoing waves and find that their squared ratios follows the Boltzmann distribution in the frequency which agrees with Hawking radiation.