# Liquid analog of the Black Hole (Part 2)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, black-holes

Similar question has been asked but did no get good answers.

We know that black hole can confine light, but can we create an ocean black hole -
which can confine surface water waves or sound waves in water?

Definition:

- What is a static water flow which can CONFINE water waves?
- Is there a configuration confining only surface waves?
- Is there a configuration confining volume waves?

Description:

Inside a confined region any water density perturbations can not propagate outside.

PS:

- Overall volume of water in the "tank" can not change so the solution
  when the water is removed faster then the waves travel is ruled out.
- There possibly can be additional objects presented in the water
  "tank".
- It can be some unsual liquid or gas, whith additional "new"
  properties.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What is part 1 of the question, could you give a link to it? And I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking about. Do you want to know if for the fluid flows you describe, something that can mathematically be described in analogy to a black hole event horizen can form? The title mislead me a bit, reading only the title I thougt the question is about the [fluid dynamics/gravity correspondance](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5780) what it is not ...

Answer (score 2):

A [quick run of "black hole analog" through google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=black+hole+analog) produces a number of hits about creating black hole analogues on Bose-Einstein condensates manipulated with light. The analogy is of course not exact but the propagation does exhibit an event horizon, with atomic currents faster than the local speed of sound, strong enough that an analogue of Hawking radiation [can hopefully be detected](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v101/i11/e110402). These analogues have been [detected experimentally](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v105/i24/e240401); for a more accessible  resource try [this article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2009/jun/16/black-hole-analogue-traps-sound).

This might sound at odds to your question, but there is no removal of the fluid, whilst the fluid involved is certainly "new" and "unusual".