# What is some analogous experiment about the black holes by using the diary product like eggs, milk?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Black hole analog experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/black-hole-analog-experiment)

I will explain my situation a little bit:

My teacher assign a experimental project that must be including the diary product: egg and milk to finish a black hole analogous experiment project, so what is some clues that could help me to finish this motivating project?

Comment: Re-asking this question with a couple of oddball restrictions only minutes after you deleted http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40790/what-are-some-home-diy-experiment-that-could-show-a-model-with-at-least-few-of-t which was closed as a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/black-hole-analog-experiment simple looks like you are trying to game the closure. The fluid answer to 4704 remain valid answers to this question when using milk (though why you would wnat to I couldn't say), and if anyone knew of a egg-based demo they could *also* answer 4704 with them.

Comment: If you just want to get more attention to the whole question of black hole demos, [you can set a bounty](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) on http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/black-hole-analog-experiment

Comment: @dmckee - It must be using both eggs and milk...

Comment: @dmckee - I have put my situation on the other problem, so can you approve my edit, so that i could set the bounty?